# Create multiple files with same names in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, touch

I need to create 8 txt files wiht name text[x], where X is number from 1 to 8.
Is there any simple construction to do that? I thought to use iteration. 
The simple method like:

```
touch text1.txt text2.txt text3.txt text4.txt text5.txt text6.txt text7.txt text8.txt
```

is not acceptable.

Comment: In Bash, using [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion): `touch text{1..8}.txt`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf that's the answer, so shouldn't be a comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without the loop by using `brace expansion` in the file name:

```
touch text{1..8}.txt
```

See `brace expansion` in the bash man pages. Unlike wildcard expansion, the file names do not have to exist for brace expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Basic for loop construction with echoing the iteration 1 - 8 as variable 'i', which you use as a piece of the file name created by touch.

```
for i in `echo {1..8}`
do touch text$i.txt
done
```

As a one liner:

```
for i in `echo {1..8}`; do touch text$i.txt; done
```

But, I think you just had the answer in a simpler format in your comments.

Comment: As you've suggested, you don't need to use a loop anyway but if you're going to, you certainly don't need to use process substitution as well. `for i in {1..8}` would be sufficient.